# KivyMD - MDDropDownItem / Custom Font and size?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

i spent a lot of time with Googling, but i dont know answer to question: 
Is possible to use custom font in element "MDDropDownItem" KivyMD.

Please, is it posible?

If yes, how?
Thank you.

**Here is example:**

```py
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

Builder.load_string(
    '''
<TestScreen>:
    MDDropDownItem:
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}

        font_style: 'h1'
        items: app.items
        dropdown_bg: [1, 1, 1, 1]
''')


class TestScreen(FloatLayout):
    pass


class Test(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        self.items = ['Item 1',
                      'Item 2',
                      'Item 3',
                      ]

        return TestScreen()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Test().run()
```

Here are screenshots without and with `font_style: 'h1'`

[image: Same output]

Comment: Check the supported styles [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HeaTTheatR/KivyMD-data/master/gallery/kivymddoc/font-styles-2.png). Then you use something like `"font_style": "H6"`. For more help you must first post a [mcve]..

Comment: I used an [`MDDropdownMenu`](https://github.com/HeaTTheatR/KivyMD/blob/master/kivymd/uix/menu.py) not an `MDDropDownItem`. Sorry.. BTW the style should be `"H1"` not `"h1"`..

Comment: @noEmbryo, thank you for a hint. It looks like good solution but all examples ([ReadTheDocs](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/menu/index.html#center-position); [Git Example](https://github.com/HeaTTheatR/KivyMD/blob/master/kivymd/uix/menu.py)  what i tried, give me error `TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)`. Please dont you have working example? Really thanks.

Comment: Well, I do but the problem is, its inside an app I've made and its not possible to extract only this code. Maybe I'll create a small example and post it as an answer when I find some time..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of a customizable `MDDropdownMenu` with changed size and colors:

```py
from functools import partial
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu
from kivymd.toast import toast
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.factory import Factory

Builder.load_string("""
<Menu@Screen>
    MDRaisedButton:
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 3 * dp(48), dp(48)
        text: 'Open menu'
        opposite_colors: True
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
        on_release: app.open_menu(self)
""")


class Test(MDApp):

    def callback_for_menu_items(self, text):
        self.menu.dismiss()
        toast(text)

    def open_menu(self, button):
        self.menu_items = [{"viewclass": "OneLineListItem",
                            "text": "Example item {}".format(i),
                            "font_style": "H5",
                            "theme_text_color": "Custom",
                            "text_color": [1, 1, 0, 1],
                            "bg_color": [1, 0, 1, 1],
                            "on_release": partial(self.callback_for_menu_items,
                                                  "Example item {}".format(i))}
                           for i in range(15)]
        self.menu = MDDropdownMenu(items=self.menu_items, width_mult=4)
        self.menu.open(button)

    def build(self):
        return Factory.Menu()


Test().run()
```

UPDATE: Added a way to manually dismiss the dropdown